# A Löwenheim–Skolem–Tarski-like property

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, model-theory, large-cardinals

I am interested in the following Löwenheim–Skolem–Tarski-like property.

Given a cardinal $\kappa$, what (if any) is a property $\phi(x)$ such that if $\phi(\kappa)$ holds, then we can prove the following: for any first-order structure $B$ (in some countable language), there is a structure $A$ in the same language with $\lvert A\rvert<\kappa$, such that for any $b \in B$ there is some elementary embedding $j:A \rightarrow B$ such that $b$ is in the range of $j$?

Note that if we don't require $b$ to be in the range of $j$, then this is the usual Löwenheim–Skolem–Tarski property, so it holds as long as $\kappa \geq \aleph_1$.

Comment: Interesting question. Noah's answer shows $\kappa>2^{\aleph_0}$. Another way to see this is to note that in a countable language, there can be $2^{\aleph_0}$-many complete types over $\varnothing$. Let $B$ be a model realizing all these types. Since a model $A$ of size $<2^{\aleph_0}$ cannot realize all these types, $B$ cannot be covered by elementary substructures isomorphic to $A$.

Comment: I tried getting a situation like this from a huge cardinal but couldn’t quite work it out.   You can find a stationary set of things that are all isomorphic to a fixed $V_\kappa$, but if there are extra constants in the language, the copies of $V_\kappa$ don’t all collapse to isomorphic models in the larger language.

Comment: @MonroeEskew I also was trying to get it from strong hypotheses. It seemed supercompactness-like using the Magidor characterization. But I also couldn't ever quite get all the details to cooperate. But I realized upon waking this morning that $0^\sharp$ makes it true in $L$, as I explain in my answer, so it is much weaker than I expected at first.

Comment: Oops, my $0^\sharp$ argument doesn't quite work, so I have deleted my answer. Currently, I don't know any upper bound on the consistency strength--it could be inconsistent as far as I know.

Comment: For how you asked the question, an answer is the following. Let $\phi(x)$ be the sentence "$x$ is a cardinal and, for any first-order structure $B$ in some countable language, there is a structure $A$ in the same language with $\lvert A\rvert<\kappa$, such that for any $b \in B$ there is some elementary embedding $j:A \rightarrow B$ such that $b$ is in the range of $j$". This can be written in first-order set theory, and it implies what you are looking for in a trivial way.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins Done!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Let me improve somewhat on Farmer's lower bound.

**Theorem.** If there is a cardinal $\kappa$ with the stated reflection property, then there are many measurable cardinals, measurable cardinals of very high Mitchell rank, and indeed, $1$-extendible cardinals of high Mitchell rank.

The update gives a cardinal $\bar\kappa$ that is $\alpha$-extendible for $\alpha$ much larger than many measurable cardinals above $\bar\kappa$. In particular, $\bar\kappa$ is highly partially supercompact.

**Proof.** Suppose that $\kappa$ has the stated reflection property. Consider some large ordinal $\theta$ and let $B=\langle V_{\theta+1},{\in}\rangle$. By the reflection property, there is some structure $A$ with lots of elementary embeddings $j:A\to B$ hitting any desired target. We may assume $A$ is a transitive set. Let $\bar\kappa$ be the smallest critical point of such an embedding. For any $X\subseteq\bar\kappa$, it is in $B$ and so there is some $x\in A$ and $j:A\to B$ with $j(x)=X$. Since $x$ and $j(x)=X$ must agree up to $\bar\kappa$, this implies $X\in A$. So $P(\bar\kappa)\subseteq A$. This implies that $\bar\kappa$ is measurable, since we can define the induced normal measure $X\in\mu\iff \bar\kappa\in j(X)$ for such a $j$ with critical point $\bar\kappa$.

So we've seen that $\bar\kappa$ is a measurable cardinal. And since $B$ also can see this, there must be measurable cardinals below $\bar\kappa$ in $A$. And indeed, the measure $\mu$ on $\bar\kappa$ will concentrate on measurables. So $\bar\kappa$ has Mitchell rank 1. But $B$ sees this, and so $\bar\kappa$ has Mitchell rank 2, and so forth, cycling around the loop for a long while to get very high Mitchell ranks.

The same idea shows that $\bar\kappa$ is 1-extendible, since we must have $V_{\bar\kappa+1}\subseteq A$ and so $j\upharpoonright V_{\bar\kappa+1}:V_{\bar\kappa+1}\to V_{j(\bar\kappa)+1}$ witnesses 1-extendibility. And since this is inside $B$, we get that $\bar\kappa$ is a limit of 1-extendibles, of high Mitchell rank again. $\Box$

If we could show $P(P(\bar\kappa))\subseteq A$, we would get $2$-extendibility, and so forth.

**Update.** Let me now explain, based on the arguments in the comments by Farmer and Andreas, that we can achieve higher degrees of extendibility. The main idea is to show that $V_{\bar\kappa+\alpha}\subseteq A$ for higher ordinals $\alpha$, which shows that $\bar\kappa$ is $\alpha$-extendible. The argument I've given above shows how the case $\alpha=1$ works. Let's now extend further.

Let $\bar\kappa_0=\bar\kappa$ be the least critical point that arises with $j:A\to B$, and let $\kappa_1$ be the next critical point. Such a critical point must arise because there must be $j:A\to B$ with $\bar\kappa$ in the range of $j$, and such an embedding must have critical point above $\bar\kappa$. What I claim is that $P(\bar\kappa_1)\subseteq A$. To see this, consider any $X\subseteq \bar\kappa_1$, and then find a $j:A\to B$ with $\{\bar\kappa,X\}\in\text{ran}(j)$. It follows that $\bar\kappa\in\text{ran}(j)$ and so the critical point of $j$ is at least $\bar\kappa_1$, and so $X\in A$ by the same reasoning as before.

The main point is that the embeddings $j:A\to B$ with critical point $\bar\kappa$ now are witnesses of $\bar\kappa_1$-extendibility, which is already a high degree of extendibility. And we can continue with $\kappa_\alpha$ etc. getting very high degrees of extendibility of $\bar\kappa$ this way. It seems we get that $\bar\kappa$ is $\alpha$-extendible, where $\alpha$ is the $\bar\kappa$th measurable cardinal above $\bar\kappa$. And much more.

Andreas mentioned in the comments an idea for pushing this further, and perhaps he will post an answer about that.

**Another feature.** There is another certain feature here I noticed that seems interesting, and we might be able to push it much harder, but I don't quite see how to use it yet. Namely, for every $\theta$ we got a small transitive set $A$ which supports the elementary embeddings $j:A\to V_{\theta+1}$. Since there are only set many such $A$, it must be that some $A$ works for unboundedly many $\theta$. That is, we have a single transitive set $A$, such that for arbitrarily large $\theta$ we have elementary embeddings $j:A\to V_{\theta+1}$ that cover the target. And there will be a $\bar\kappa$ in $A$ that is the critical point of such an embedding for arbitrarily large $\theta$. That seems powerful, but I'm not sure exactly how to use it. It isn't quite super-$1$-extendibility, since perhaps it isn't $\bar\kappa$ that is sent high, even though the target model of $A$ can be made high.

Comment: How do you define the map $j \colon A \to B$ inside $L$? Clearly, this map exists in $V$,  but I don't see how to define it in $L$.

Comment: Hmmn. I think you are right. This argument doesn't work after all. I shall delete.

Comment: I've posted a totally new argument, using and extending Farmer's idea, to provide a better lower bound.

Comment: Nice. Don't we get $P(P(\bar{\kappa}))\subseteq A$ as follows? Let $\bar{\kappa}_0=\bar{\kappa}$, and given $\bar{\kappa}_n$, let $

Comment: I'd love to get $P(P(\bar\kappa))\subseteq A$, but your comment seems to be cut off.

Comment: Joel, if we let $\bar\kappa_1$ to be the least critical point of an elementary $j:A\rightarrow B$ with $\bar\kappa$ in the range of $j$, then we get that $\mathcal P(\bar\kappa_1)\subseteq A$ and $\bar\kappa_1$ is measurable, etc.

Comment: @AndreasLietz Could you explain more? The $j$s with that critical point might not hit all the subsets of $\kappa_1$.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins They have to, for any $X\subseteq\bar\kappa_1$ there must be some $j$ with $\{\bar\kappa, X\}$ in the range of $j$. Then your argument above should work as $j$ must have critical point $\geq\bar\kappa_1$.

Comment: Ah, I see. So this will give high degrees of extendibility. This might reach up toward Farmer's upper bound. We are closing in. I am preparing dinner now, and will come back later and edit this in.

Comment: I believe one can find a measurbale $\lambda$ so that $V_\lambda$ has a proper class of (full) extendibles, but I do not see how to push this much further.

Comment: @AndreasLietz I suggest you post an answer with that result.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins Done!

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins Thank you for the fantastic answer! Also thank all the other that answered this question. I chose the answer of Professor Hamkins as correct because I personally learned much from the reasoning in it.

I am a master student in set theory, and this notion of LST cardinal is a variant of one of the notions introduced and studied in my thesis work. Benefited from some of the insights I learned here, I think there are possible ways to give more precise bounds on the strength of the notion in my thesis, by connecting it to some other notions I am looking at.

Answer (score 18):

Here's a counterexample for $\kappa=\aleph_1$: let $B$ be the structure with underlying set $\mathbb{N}\sqcup\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$, equipped with the usual ordering on $\mathbb{N}$ as well as the $\in$-relation between the $\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ parts. We need continuum-many countable structures to "cover" this $B$, since the elements of the $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$-part are elementarily distinguishable.

(FWIW a similar trick is used to whip up a countable structure - necessarily in an uncountable language - with no countable proper elementary extension.)

Answer (score 17):

Here is an upper bound:

Suppose $\kappa$ is $2$-fold supercompact. Then the property holds at $\kappa$. (Recall that $2$-fold supcompactness means that for each ordinal $\lambda$, there is $j:V\to M$ with $\mathrm{crit}(j)=\kappa$ and $\lambda<j(\kappa)$ and ${^{j(\lambda)}M}\subseteq M$.) (This property is of course below rank-to-rank.)

So suppose $B$ is a counterexample to the property holding at $\kappa$.

Let $\lambda>\kappa$ be an inaccessible cardinal such that $B\in V_\lambda$. (There is easily a proper class of inaccessibles.)
Using $2$-fold supercompactness at $\lambda$, let $j:V\to M$ with $\mathrm{crit}(j)=\kappa$ and $\lambda<j(\kappa)$ and ${^{j(\lambda)}M}\subseteq M$. It follows that $B\in V_{j(\kappa)}=V_{j(\kappa)}^M$. Note also that because ${^{j(\lambda)}M}\subseteq M$ and $\lambda$ is inaccessible, we have $V_{j(\lambda)+1}^M=V_{j(\lambda)+1}$.

Let $C=j(B)$. We have $C\in V_{j(\lambda)}\subseteq M$. Note that $C$ is a counterexample to $j(\kappa)$ having the property in $M$.
Since $B\in V_{j(\kappa)}^M$, we can fix $x\in C=j(B)$ such that $M\models$"there is no elementary $\ell:B\to C$ with $x\in\mathrm{range}(\ell)$". But since $V_{j(\lambda)}\subseteq M$, therefore in fact ($*$) there is no elementary $\ell:B\to C$ with $x\in\mathrm{range}(\ell)$.

Now applying $j$ to ($*$),
we get that $M\models$"there is no elementary $\ell:j(B)\to j(C)$ with $j(x)\in\mathrm{range}(\ell)$". But letting $\ell=j\upharpoonright j(B)$, we have $\ell\in M$, since ${^{j(\lambda)}M}\subseteq M$. And  $x\in j(B)$, so $\ell(x)=j(x)\in\mathrm{range}(\ell)$. This is a contradiction.

---

Here is a lower bound:

If the property holds at some $\kappa$ then $0^\#$ exists.

For suppose the property holds at $\kappa$.
Let $B$ be a transitive model of ZFC$^-$
with $V_\kappa\subseteq B$.
Let $A$
witness the property with respect to $B,\kappa$, so in particular, $A$ has cardinality ${<\kappa}$.
Let $\alpha=\mathrm{Ord}\cap A$.
Let $\theta=\mathrm{card}(\alpha)$.
If there is any elementary embedding $j:A\to B$
such that $\mathrm{crit}(j)<\theta$,
then $0^\#$ exists (this is standard: letting $k:L_\alpha\to L_{\mathrm{Ord}^B}$
be the restriction of $j$, then
$k$ is elementary, and letting $U_k$
be the normal measure derived from $k$,
then $\mathrm{Ult}(L,U_k)$ is wellfounded,
giving an elementary $\ell:L\to L$).

So we may assume that
every $j:A\to B$ witnessing the property
in question has $\theta\leq\mathrm{crit}(j)$. Now given $X\subseteq\theta$,
we have $X\cup\{\theta\}\in B$, so there is $j_X:A\to B$
with $X,\theta\in\mathrm{rg}(j_X)$.
Since $\theta\leq\mathrm{crit}(j_X)$,
in fact then $\theta<\mathrm{crit}(j_X)$,
and it follows that $X$ is definable from parameters over $A$,
and since $A\models$ ZFC$^-$,
therefore $X\in A$.
But then every wellorder of $\theta$ is in $A$, and again since $A\models$ ZFC$^-$,
it follows that $\theta^{+}\leq\mathrm{Ord}\cap A$, a contradiction.

---

Added remarks: From Joel's and Andreas's answers, if $\kappa$ has the property then there are partially extendible cardinals ${<\kappa}$, and there is $\lambda<\kappa$ such that $V_\lambda\models$ ZFC + "there are (fully) extendible cardinals". So assuming that there exist both a cardinal $\kappa$ with the property, and a (truly) extendible cardinal $\gamma$, we can ask what is the relative ordering of the least such two cardinals $\kappa_0$ and $\gamma_0$.

Prop 1: Suppose $\kappa_0$ (the least with said property) and $\gamma_0$ (the least extendible) exist. Then $\kappa_0<\gamma_0$.

Proof: First let us show that if $\kappa$ has the property and $\gamma$ is extendible, then $\gamma$ also has the property. If $\kappa\leq\gamma$ this is immediate, so suppose $\gamma<\kappa$.
Let $B$ be given, and let $\alpha$ be such that $B\in V_\alpha$. Let $j:V_\alpha\to V_\beta$ be elementary with $\mathrm{crit}(j)=\gamma$ and $j(\gamma)>\kappa$. Then by the property at $\kappa$ with respect to $j(B)$, there is $A\in V_{\kappa}$ such that $A$ can be embedded into $j(B)$ with any desired $x\in j(B)$ in the range. But $V_\kappa\subseteq V_{j(\gamma)}$, and $j(B)\in V_\beta$, so all the witnessing embeddings are in $V_\beta$, so $V_\beta$ thinks that there is an appropriate $A\in V_{j(\gamma)}$ for $j(B)$. But then $V_\alpha$ thinks there is an appropriate $A\in V_\gamma$ for $B$, and this really works in $V$, as desired.

So we have $\kappa_0\leq\gamma_0$. The rest follows from the following lemma:

Lemma: If $\kappa$ is a superstrong cardinal that has the property, then there there is $\kappa'<\kappa$ with the property.

Proof: Suppose otherwise and let $f:\kappa\to V$ be a function where $f(\kappa')$ is some $B$ witnessing that the property fails at $\kappa'$, with $B$ of minimal rank to achieve this. Then note that by superstrongness (in fact just strongness) of $\kappa$, we have $f(\kappa')\in V_\kappa$ for each $\kappa'<\kappa$. Now let $j:V\to M$ witness the superstrongness of $\kappa$ and let $B=j(f)(\kappa)$. In $M$, $B$ is a counterexample to $\kappa$ having the property. But we have $B\in V_{j(\kappa)}^M=V_{j(\kappa)}$, and since $\kappa$ has the property in $V$, it follows that $B$ is actually not a counterexample in $M$, contradiction.

Prop 2: Let $\kappa_0$ be the least cardinal with the property. Suppose $V_{\kappa_0}\models$ ZFC. Then there is no $\gamma<\kappa_0$ which is $\kappa_0$-extendible (that is, there is no elementary $j:V_{\kappa_0}\to V_\beta$ (for some $\beta$) with $\mathrm{crit}(j)=\gamma<\kappa_0$ and $j(\gamma)>\kappa_0$).

Proof: Suppose otherwise. Then the property holds at $\gamma$ with respect to all $B\in V_{\kappa_0}$. (If $B$ is a counterexample, note that $V_\beta\models$"$j(B)$ is a counterexample to the property holding at $j(\gamma)$", but since $\kappa_0\leq j(\gamma)$ and the property holds at $\kappa_0$, actually $V_\beta\models$"no it's not", contradiction.) But then the property holds at $\gamma$ with respect to *all* structures $B$: given $B$, let $B'\in V_{\kappa_0}$ witness the property at $\kappa_0$ with respect to $B$, and now let $A\in V_\gamma$ witness it at $\gamma$ with respect to $B'$. Let $x\in B$, and let $k:B'\to B$ with $x\in\mathrm{range}(k)$. Then there is $k':A\to B'$ with $k^{-1}(x)\in\mathrm{range}(k')$. Now $k\circ k':A\to B$ works. So the property holds at $\gamma$, contradicting the minimality of $\kappa_0$.

Some related questions: Let $\kappa_0$ be the least cardinal with the property. Can/does $V_{\kappa_0}\models$ ZFC? Can/does $V_{\kappa_0}\models$"There is an extendible cardinal"?

Comment: Can't we argue $\kappa_0<\gamma_0$ more simply like this: having the reflective property is $\Pi_2$ expressible. So if it exists, $\kappa_0$ is below every $\Sigma_3$-correct cardinal, and extendibles are $\Sigma_3$ correct. So $\kappa_0<\gamma_0$.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins: Re $\kappa_0<\gamma_0$: I see, I was complicating it unnecessarily. And yes, got the email.

Answer (score 15):

Here is a lower bound that improves Joel's by a bit. If the reflection property of the post holds at $\kappa$ then there is some measurable $\lambda<\kappa$ with
$$V_\lambda\models``\text{there is a proper class of extendible cardinals}".$$
In fact, we can have $\lambda$ itself somewhat extendible if we want to. Let $A, B$ be as in Joel's answer, so for any $b\in B$ there is an elementary $j_b:A\rightarrow B$ with $b\in\mathrm{ran}(j_b)$ (and say we pick $j_b$ with minimal possible critical point).

We now define an increasing sequence $\langle \bar\kappa_\beta\mid\beta<\alpha\rangle$ and only stop when we hit a limit $\alpha$ so that $\sup_{\beta<\alpha}\bar\kappa_\beta$ is measurable. By recursion, we let
$$\bar\kappa_\beta:=\min\{\mathrm{crit}(j_{\{b, \langle \bar\kappa_\gamma\mid\gamma<\beta\rangle\}})\mid b\in B\}.$$
We have to show that we hit the stopping $\alpha$ before the sequence is no longer increasing. So suppose instead that we find some $\beta<\xi$ with $\bar\kappa_\xi\leq\bar\kappa_\beta$ first and let $(\xi,\beta)$ be lexicographically least so. Now we can find $j:A\rightarrow B$ with $\mathrm{crit}(j)=\bar\kappa_\xi$ and $\langle\bar\kappa_\gamma\mid\gamma<\xi\rangle$ in the range of $j$, say its preimage is $\langle \bar\lambda_\gamma\mid\gamma<\bar\xi\rangle$. If defined, we have $\bar\kappa_\xi\leq\bar\kappa_{\bar\kappa_\xi}$, so by minimality of $\beta$ necessarily $\beta\leq\bar\kappa_\xi$. If we had $\beta<\bar\kappa_\xi$ then $j(\langle\bar\lambda_\gamma\mid\gamma<\beta\rangle)=\langle \bar\kappa_\gamma\mid\gamma<\beta\rangle$ is in the range of $j$, so that $\bar\kappa_\beta=\bar\kappa_\xi$ by definition of $\bar\kappa_\beta$. But $\bar\kappa_\beta=j(\bar\lambda_\beta)$ is in the range of $j$, yet $\bar\kappa_\beta=\mathrm{crit}(j)$, contradiction. We are left with $\bar\kappa_\xi=\beta$. Joel's argument shows that $\beta$ must be measurable: We only need to see $\mathcal P(\beta)\subseteq A$. Now for $X\subseteq\beta$, $X$ is in the range of $j_{\{X,\langle \bar\kappa_\gamma\mid\gamma<\xi\rangle\}}$ and this map has critical point $\geq \beta$. This can only happen if already $X\in A$.
We have $\bar\kappa_\gamma<\bar\kappa_\xi=\beta$ for $\gamma<\beta$ by minimality of $\beta$, so that $\sup_{\gamma<\beta}\bar\kappa_\gamma=\beta$ should have been our stopping point, contradiction!

So we set $\lambda=\sup_{\beta<\alpha}\kappa_\beta$ (actually $\lambda=\alpha)$ which is measurable by construction. We have that $\langle \bar\kappa_\beta\mid\beta<\lambda\rangle$ is an increasing cofinal sequence in $\lambda$ and we will show that unboundedly many of those are extendible in $V_\lambda$. Once again, $V_\lambda\subseteq A$ by applying Joel's argument to all $\bar\kappa_\beta$ for $\beta<\lambda$.

So any $\bar\kappa_\beta$ is $\lambda$-extendible, i.e. there is some $\nu_\beta$ and $k_\beta\colon V_\lambda\rightarrow V_{\nu_\beta}$ with critical point $\bar\kappa_\beta$. By Dushnik-Miller, there is some $H\in[\lambda]^\lambda$ so that $\nu_\beta\leq\nu_\gamma$ for every $\beta<\gamma$ both in $H$.

We are done once we show that $\bar\kappa_\beta$ is extendible in $V_\lambda$ for $\beta\in H$, since those $\bar\kappa_\beta$ are cofinal in $\lambda$. It is enough to show that if $\beta<\gamma$ are both in $H$ then $\bar\kappa_\beta$ is ${<}\bar\kappa_\gamma$-extendible in $V_\lambda$. Let $$\mu:=k_\beta(\bar\kappa_\gamma)<\nu_\beta\leq\nu_\gamma.$$
Then $k_\beta\upharpoonright V_{\bar\kappa_\gamma}:V_{\bar\kappa_\gamma}\rightarrow V_\mu$ is elementary, has critical point $\bar\kappa_\beta$ and is in $V_{\nu_\gamma}$. By elementarity of $k_\gamma$, we must have $V_\lambda\models``\bar\kappa_\beta\text{ is $\delta$-extendible}"$ for each $\delta<\bar\kappa_\gamma$.